# Use $2, $1, etc. in a text file?

Tags: irc, mirc

First off let me say sorry for the wording on this, I am new to coding in mIRC and don't quite know the terms and/or how to do what I want.

My goal is to use whatever the term for "$1" in a text file, such as this text file with a line containing the following

```
hello something
```

I would like for it to then write the following in a new text file.

```
hello
```

I know this is a subpar example, but I am sure one of you will be able to help me. Along with a solution, I would appreciate if someone would share where they found this information along with where I can learn more about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://en.wikichip.org/wiki/mirc is a great source.

But to answer your question:

For this you would use [$read](http://en.wikichip.org/wiki/mirc/text_files), to read the line from your file.
`$read(file.txt,n,1)`, this will read line number 1 from the file `file.txt`.

You can assign this to a variable, so `var %line = $read(file.txt,n,1)`, this will assign the content from line 1 in `file.txt` to `%line`.

After having the content stored in `%file` you can use [$gettok](http://en.wikichip.org/wiki/mirc/token_manipulation#Lists) to retrieve the first word. The delimiter in your case is a space, so you use 32. For other values look here: http://www.asciitable.com/ and select from the `dec` column. `$gettok(%line,1,32)` will get you the first word.

You can, again, store this in a variable if needed and [write](http://en.wikichip.org/wiki/mirc/text_files) it in another .txt file.

Extra:
Have a look at [/tokenize](http://en.wikichip.org/wiki/mirc/commands/tokenize), you can use this instead of $gettok, this will make it easier for you to use `$1`, `$2` etc, after. It will also slightly improve the [performance](http://en.wikichip.org/wiki/mirc/optimization#.2Ftokenize_.26_.24n_vs_.24gettok.28.29).

Comment: Hey denny, if I wanted to retrieve the second word, would i change it to `$gettok(%line,2,32)` ? Also, am i able to reword `%line` as I think it is used elsewhere.

Comment: Good examples and explanations up for that